# How to catch error using $fetch in Nuxt 3

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt3(SSR: false), I have login form with email/password, the issue when I send the form and my server return 422 error with message error I cannot console it.

Here is my code:

```
async login() {
  const response = await $fetch('/login', {
    method: 'POST',
    baseURL: this.baseURL,
    body: this.form,
    watch: false,
  }).catch((err) => err.data)

  console.log('err', err)
},
```

**And here is result:**

[image: DeveloperConsole_ErrorScreenshot]

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error, I managed to read the error message using `useFetch`:

```js
const { data, error } = await useFetch('/login', {
  method: 'POST',
  baseURL: this.baseURL,
  body: this.form,
})
if (data.value) {
   // handle success
} else {
   console.log('error', error.value.data.message) 
}
```